# How can I launch Appium Node Server using batch file?

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, appium

When we execute the batch script mentioned below, appium is getting open. However, the script is not getting executed. When you click on "Launch Appium Node Server", the script run. I have installed node js, and configured the environmental variable.

```
START "node" /D "<C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium>" "node.exe"
START "node" /D "<C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server>" "main.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app "C:\SyxData\mPO.apk" --pre-launch --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --device-name 'Moto G2' --log-no-color"
```

Comment: Do you really have the `<>` characters surrounding the path after the `/D` switch?? you need to remove them...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by creating a new enviornmental variable with name node, and the desired path. This has allowed me to automate my mobile application in Jenkins.